# Правильное построение цикла Python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

**Доброго времени суток!**

Необходимо создать цикл по которому будет отбиратся одно значение из массива и отправляться по команде.

```
import telebot
import random


bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

picture = random.choice(['url1', 'url2', 'url3'])

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_pic(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'картинка':
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, picture)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

*только начинаю все осваивать*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас уже выбирается случайным образом одна картинка из списка. Если вы хотите, чтобы при каждой команде картинка выбиралась заново, то нужно переместить выбор картинки поближе к её отсылке, например так:

```
import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_pic(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'картинка':
        picture = random.choice(['url1', 'url2', 'url3'])
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, picture)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Если же вы хотите, например, отослать сразу все картинки из списка по очереди в ответ на одну команду, то тут уже можно использовать цикл:

```
import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_pic(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'картинка':
        for picture in ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, picture)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Не знаю, можно ли так делать в боте, но принцип работы с циклами такой.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь